# Erro ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle

I am creating a view using case statements and subqueries, it is executed and shows

```
ORA-01427 "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

How can I return just one row to fix it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW AAAA("BB",  "CC") AS
SELECT T1.C1, 
CASE WHEN T2.C1='RED' THEN (SELECT COLOR_RED FROM T1 )
     WHEN T2.C1='GREEN' THEN (SELECT COLOR_GREEN FROM T1)
     WHEN T2.C1='BLUE' THEN (SELECT COLOR_BLUE FROM T1)
ELSE NULL END
FROM T1, T2;
```

Comment: `...THEN color_red` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to use IN or ANY with your subquery results.

Answer (score 0):

Your coding error causing the compilation/runtime exception is that you are executing inline subqueries that must return only a single value to work, but the table (T1) has more that one row in it. Your subqueries must have a WHERE clause on a primary key or uniquely-indexed combination of column values, or the T1 table must not contain more than one row. 
Also, do you intend to combine and multiply every row in T1 with every row in T2?  Your SELECT statement contains no join condition. If T1 contains 1,000 rows and T2 contains 2,000 rows, then your view will return 2,000,000 records.  Google 'SQL Cartesian Product' or 'SQL Cross Join'.